# Literary magazines that publish surreal/absurdist fiction?

Tags: publishing, short-story, genre, magazines

Does anybody know of any literary magazines that publish surreal/absurdist fiction? I have a short story I'm looking to submit. The closest comparisons I can think of are A Clockwork Orange, Brave New World, Fahrenheit 451, a little bit of Lolita?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post may help you: [What journals publish surreal fiction?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/34543/what-journals-publish-surreal-fiction)

As is mentioned in a comment on that entry, I also recommend Duotrope as well as Google search. Duotrope will let you select genre, subgenre, and style. There are a number of different combinations you can hunt up, including both science fiction and fantasy. Duotrope checks their listings regularly, so you have information on whether the journal is still active and when they are accepting submissions. Always check the website for the individual journal to see what their submission process is. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Could you upvote and mark my answer as the correct one? Thanks!

Comment: Yep, just did! :-)